# pandas MultiIndex with mixed format: change format of level 0 "%b-%Y" as datetime values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, multi-index

python 3.6 pandas 1.1.2 on windows 10

Trying to change the date format of the level 0 of a MultiIndex, while keeping the values as datetime.  For example:

```
dates = pd.date_range(start='2017-01-01', end='2020-12-01', freq='M')
n = [1, 2, 3, 4]
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dates, n], names=['date', 'n'])
```

`idx[:5]` Gives:

```
MultiIndex([('2017-01-31', 1),
                ('2017-01-31', 2),
                ('2017-01-31', 3),
                ('2017-01-31', 4),
                ('2017-02-28', 1)],
               names=['date', 'n'])
```

Where: `type(idx.get_level_values(0))` is

```
class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'
```

Now, I would like to change the dates values to show only month and year, while retaining their type. For example:

```
MultiIndex([('Jan-2017', 1),
            ('Jan-2017', 2),
            ('Jan-2017', 3),
            ('Jan-2017', 4),
            ('Feb-2017', 1)],
           names=['date', 'n'])
```

Comment: afaik you cannot change the format pandas uses to *display* datetime - you have to change the type to string to see a different format. I wouldn't care about the looks while *working* with the data - correct type matters. you can always apply a nice format if you want to show/present something.

Comment: True that, and thanks for your answer. 
As I need to build and chain pandas pivot tables (where dates order matters) around these data, my work around has been to have the index in the form of string: '%Y-%m'. Less cute than month name, but does the job in keeping dates ordered.